# How to get result from mysql when using Count(*) As

Tags: php, mysql, sql

how can I get the result if this in php when my query is the following:

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS call_count FROM `callsepaug` ";
        $query .= "WHERE start_time BETWEEN '" . $start_date . "' AND ";
        $query .= "'" . $end_date . "'";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the same as a simple query, you can `get count(*)` with `call_count`

```
$queryBuild = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS call_count FROM `callsepaug` ";
        $queryBuild .= "WHERE start_time BETWEEN '" . $start_date . "' AND ";
        $queryBuild .= "'" . $end_date . "'");

$query = mysqli_query($queryBuild);

$result =  mysqli_fetch_array($query);

echo $result['call_count'];
```

Or with object

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS call_count FROM `callsepaug` ";
        $query .= "WHERE start_time BETWEEN '" . $start_date . "' AND ";
        $query .= "'" . $end_date . "'";

$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
echo $row["call_count"];
```

Comment: Your first example is a mistake , you are assigning mysql_query(..) to $query and then adding where clause , you must concatenate before mysqli_query ...

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS call_count FROM `callsepaug` ";
        $query .= "WHERE start_time BETWEEN '" . $start_date . "' AND ";
        $query .= "'" . $end_date . "'";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
$row_array=$result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
print($row_array['TOTALFOUND']);
```

Note: Mysql_* functions are deprecated. Avoid using these functions.

Answer (score 0):

Incidentally, you can write that code this way...

```
$query = "
SELECT COUNT(*) call_count 
  FROM callsepaug
 WHERE start_time BETWEEN '$start_date' AND '$end_date';
 ";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS call_count FROM `callsepaug` ";
        $query .= "WHERE start_time BETWEEN '" . $start_date . "' AND ";
        $query .= "'" . $end_date . "'");

$result =  mysql_fetch_array($query);

echo $result[0];
```